# 3 Way Timer Light Switch Leviton LTB30

Tags: switch, light, timer

I have a 3-way timer switch that I want to install in the house to control the lights outside and I can’t figure out how to wire it, maybe I need a no neutral switch, or a jumper. I currently have an LTB30 timer switch from Leviton. It has Red, Black, White, and Yellow/Red. My 3 ways only have Red, Black, White. When I put the voltmeter from the wire to box, this is what I get:

Lights off

Garage Switch
Red 120 volts
Black 120 volts
White 0 Volts

House Switch
Red 120 volts
Black 0 volts
White 0 Volts

Lights on

Garage Switch
Red 50 volts
Black 120 volts
White 120 volts

House Switch
Red 120 volts
Black 120 volts
White 100 volts

Any help would be appreciated

Garage
[image: Garage]

House
[image: House]

Comment: Can you post photos looking into the backs of the boxes in question please?

Comment: Per the instructions (https://www.leviton.com/en/docs/Instruction_Sheet.pdf), you need a neutral wire in each box (which you don't seem to have) and a matching remote switch in the other box, not the 3-way switch you currently have.

Comment: Are the white and red wires on the brass screws?